# BEM - Where to include modifiers for specific pages?

Tags: css, bem

I am trying to use BEM naming convention and having some slight difficulty in deciding where to include a modifier for a specific page.

For example, say I have an orange button:

```
<button class="btn btn-orange">Button A</button>
```

My project has 3 different pages:

```
 - pageA.html - pageA.scss
 - pageB.html - pageB.scss
 - pageC.html - pageC.scss
```

On `pageB.html` the button should have a `margin-top:30px`. Is it correct to write the modifier this way:

```
.btn {
  padding: 5px 20px;
  background: orange;
  margin: 0

  &--margin-top {
    margin-top: 30px;
  }
}
```

And what is the best way to include a modifier like that only for a specific page? In this case that would be for `pageB.html`. Should I include that modifier inside the `pageB.scss` or `.buttons.scss`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you're confusing two concepts here - **BEM**, which is **Naming Convention** with the problem of structuring your projects. Both have nothing to do with each other, and I think BEM is not opinionated in terms of structuring your SASS files.

But, there's a couple of questions you ask here:

1. *Is it correct to write the modifier this way?* - it is correct if you want to stick to **BEM** convention, although I would say, the name you picked `.btn--margin-top` might not be very fortunate in a long term - imagine, you'll want to include another `btn` modifier with `margin-top` property set to, let's say `40px`. How will you name it?
2. *What is the best way to include a modifier like that only for a specific page?* - These CSS classes you are usually not making for specific page. Whole point of **BEM** is to enable you, to write more modular CSS, and having this in mind you should use these CSS classes, by assigning them to your Blocks/Elements/Modifiers respectively. Trick here is to determine what is a block/element/modifier in your markup. What you'll achieve by this is reusable CSS, so you can quickly apply same css, by adding BEM classes.
   Think in terms of **Blocks** or **Components**, NOT pages. You want to use it only on `pageB` - just add `btn--margin-top` class to your `pageB` markup.
3. *Should I include that modifier inside the `pageB.scss` or .`buttons.scss`?* - it depends on how you structure your project, and I would say that usually, buttons and other UI elements, are in most cases common to whole website/webapp, so there is no need of having them "attached" to specific page (which concept I think you need to drop, if you want to take full advantage of BEM). Besides, whatever suits you will be good for you, and unless you're not working within a team of developers, just stick to your own method, so you'll know in future where to look for things.

Comment: I've seen some videos, articles and tutorials about BEM. But your definition about BEM was the best one so far I've ever seen. You should consider writing an article about it as this is a practical definition and it's easier to pick it up. Again thank you very much for helping me understand this.

Comment: Thanks @brunodd for this response, and I'm really glad, it helped you out. This really encourages me, to do some writing on this topic, as you suggested. I'll keep you updated on this ;)

Comment: I've been wondering about the question of page-specific BEM selectors for a while and your answer makes sense. I guess the point of using BEM is to be able to reuse blocks across the site. But maybe there are cases where a block will only ever be on one page? I wonder if it would make sense to include a page-specific prefix to help the developer target where it's being used then. But then again, a quick codebase search would give a more definitive answer for this--since often CSS doesn't stay contained to the original developer's intended location.

Answer (score 1):

In production sites I solve this problem by using a file for the page that is deliberately more specific.

The other answerer is correct, BEM doesn't solve this problem but the solution is available in the css architecture.

I tend to structure projects as follows:

- modules
- sections
- pages

with each getting more specific.

A section might have some specific way of rendering a button, in which case the sass would be like this:

```
.section {
  .button--primary {
    // styles 
  }
}
```

For a page, the same, but with a page specific key:

```
.page {
  .button--primary {
    // styles 
  }
}
```

You could even do:

```
.page {
  .section {
    .button--primary {
      // styles 
    }
  }
}
```

The key is keeping on top of the specificity in the structure of you sass files. Your button file would not change and you could be sure of dropping it in anywhere in the HTML of your site and having it render correctly and, as a module, it should only contain styles you would want to apply site-wide. For example:

```
.button--call-to-action {
  background-color: $brand-colours__call-to-action;
}
```

(the hyphens are used to denote that `call-to-action` is a variation of `button` and the underscores to denote that `call-to-action` is one of a set of colours that belong to `brand-colours`)

Your margin top would then be defined simply as `margin-top: 20px;` in part of your sass that limited it's effect to the desired portion of the site.

As an aside, usually find that almost everything in the specific page files can be refactored further up the chain into variations of sections and modules, meaning often that they end up empty.